# Error while loading scikit-learn KNNImputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I have tried to load KNNImputer in my jupyter notebook but I am facing the following error: -

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'KNNImputer' from 'sklearn.impute' (C:\Users\karti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute.py)
```

Can anyone pease help me out with this issue?

Comment: Can you check which scikit-learn version you have. Try run this in Jupyter `import sklearn;print(sklearn.__version__)` KNNImputer was introduced in version 0.22.

Comment: The version is 0.20.4.

Comment: You need to update to atlease 0.22 ;)

Comment: you can upgrade the version of sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

Check scikit-learn version. Execute in Jupyter

```py
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

KNNImputer was introduced in version 0.22. So if you have any version below that, you would not be able to import.

Given that you are using conda, as from your error, I would do the following:

```sh
# Update conda, create environment named ml and activate it
conda update --name base conda -- yes && conda create -- name ml python=3.7 scikit-learn '>=0.22.0' pandas jupyterlab --yes && conda activate ml

# run Jupyter Lab
jupyter lab
```

This should give environment with what you need. If you want to add more packages just do

```sh
conda install -n ml package_name
```

You have to be in ml environment before starting Jupyter Lab or using Python with the correct packages.

```sh
conda activate ml
python -c "import sklearn;print(sklearn.__version__)"
```

Comment: I have tried installing sklearn through pip but the version still remains the same.
Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: try installing through conda.

Comment: How did you install it? Do you use pure python or are you in environment(conda or venv)?

Comment: I am using python through my cmd.
Not any venv.

Comment: Run on CMD `python -c "import sklearn;print(sklearn.__version__)"` This should be the same with Jupyter if that is the python executed in Jupyter. Run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip && python -m pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`

Comment: in your above message-> __"\karti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute.py"__ it shows you are using anaconda. better do conda update sklearn.

Comment: Best is to use environment and not mess your base. I will update my answer above.